If a 9-digit number 32x4115y2 is divisible by 88, then the value of (4x – y) for the smallest possible value of y is :
Help me solve this problem
The problem states that the number is divisible by 88, which means it must satisfy both the divisibility rules for 11 and 8.
My approach:
To check divisibility by 88:

Divisibility by 8: Let ( y = 1 ), which gives us ( 512 ). Since ( 512 ) is divisible by 8, this condition is satisfied.
Divisibility by 11: The number is ( 32x4115y2 ). Applying the divisibility rule for 11:

[
(3 + x + 1 + 5 + 2) - (2 + 4 + 1 + 1) = 11 + x - 8 = 3 + x
]
...
... /stuck here
The answer provided is:
[
x = 8, y = 1, 4x - y = 31.
]
I am unable to understand how ( x = 8 ) was obtained. Any help is appreciated!

By divisibility rule of $11$, $11$ divides $(3 + x + 1 + 5 + 2) - (2 + 4 + 1 + y) = 4+x-y$ (here's your mistake, you wrote $1$ instead of $y$). Then you have $4+x-y = 11k$,  for some $k \geq 0$. If you put $y=1$, you get $x = 8$ (as $x$ is a digit, $0\leq x\leq 9$)

but i already got y value why cant i use it to get the correct x value ?

Yeah, you got $y = 1$, substitute to get appropriate $x$ value.

you said that putting 1 was a mistake....

Check the line in which you wrote "stuck here" Compare that line with my first comment. You'll understand.

nvm i understood.
